# Перевести форматированную дату в секунды

Tags: дата, форматирование, php, время

Здравствуйте.

Есть дата формата дд.мм.гг *(04.05.2013)*. Подскажите как можно перевести её в [секунды от начала эпохи Unix](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIX-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F)? :)

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: погуглить не пробовали ?

Comment: если бы был результат сюда не писал. буду очень рад если ткнете носом на нужный в гугл запрос.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

Comment: Благодарю.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
function dateformat($date)
{
    $date_explode = explode(".", $date);
    $date = $date_explode[2] . '-' . $date_explode[1] . '-' . $date_explode[0];
    return $date;
}

echo strtotime("".$date." 00:00:00PM");
```

Не знаю, может поможет).

Comment: Да, спасибо. Но я думаю одного strtotime вполне хватит.

Comment: @MyNameIs, неправильное представление даты в случае с разделительными точками произойдет только если год будет указан двумя цифрами. И что-то вы очень все усложнили... 
$date = preg_replace('/^(\d{1,2})\\.(\d{1,2})\\.(\d{2})$/', '$3-$2-$1', $date);